# Trying to load an array using pointers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to load an array using pointers. I am assigned my x[0] the value of 2, and the desired output is 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.

For some reason, my loop starts at index 4 or it starts at index 2 and only prints 2, 4, 8, 16.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    
    int x[7] = {}, *ip;
    ip = &(x[0]);
    
    *ip = 2;
    
    for(int i = 0; *ip < sizeof x; *ip *= 2) {
        printf("value of x: %d\n", x[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; *ip < sizeof x; *ip *= 2)` - I'm really confused what you are thinking you are doing here, but it is definitely not what your description says it does

Comment: First two lines should be `int x[7] = {0};` and `int *ip = x;`

Comment: `math.h` is unneeded, `i` is always `0`, `ip` is always `x`, only `x[0]` is used of the `x[7]`, so refactoring for a 32-byte-int, `for(int x = 2; x < 28; x *= 2) printf("value of x: %d\n", x);`. Not surprising at all.

Comment: `int x[7] = {}` is not allowed in Standard C - I would recommend invoking your compiler in standard mode as you will get better diagnostics

Comment: `sizeof x` is probably 28 on your system, so the loop stops before printing `32` . If you replace that with `129` for example then you will see up to 129.

Answer (score 1):

Following the perceived intent of your code, that is, to fill an array by using a pointer, I corrected it to the below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[7] = {0};
    int *p, counter;

    for (p = &x[0], counter = 0; counter < 7;) {
        *p++ = (1 << ++counter);
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
        printf("%d\n", x[counter]);
}
```

I initialise `x` and declare a pointer `int *p`. I also declare a variable `counter` to count to the number of elements in the array.

At the start of the loop I point `p` to the address of the first element of the array `x` and initialise `counter` to 0.

In each loop iteration I set the value at the address pointed by `p` to the result of a left-shift (or l-shift) operation and increment pointer `p` (that is, advance it by `sizeof(int)` bytes). The l-shift operation has the effect of raising 2 to the power of *n*, where *n* is the number of l-shift positions. For example:

```
(1 << 0) = 1
(1 << 1) = 2
(1 << 2) = 4
(1 << 3) = 8
```

I use the post-increment operator for `p` (that is, `*p++`) because I want to set the value before advancing it. But I use the pre-increment operator for `counter` (that is, `++counter`) because I want the first l-shift to be by *1* position so that the result stored in the first element of the array is *2* -- refer to example above.

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended on SO - please explain your code (and including explanation of OP's problems would be good)

Comment: @M.M --- Noted.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; *ip < sizeof x; *ip *= 2) {
        printf("value of x: %d\n", x[i]);
    }
```

will print `x[i]` till the value at memory location pointed by pointer `ip` is less than the size of object `x` in bytes.  Note that `i` is initialised with `0` but it is nowhere altered.

Assume that size of `int` on your system is `4` bytes, the `sizeof x` will yield `28` because `x` is an array of `7` integers (`7 * 4 = 28`).

Iteration I:

```
i = 0          //initialized
*ip = 2,  2 < 28   ---->    true
print x[0]         ---->    2
*ip *= 2           ---->    *ip = 4
```

Iteration II:

```
*ip = 4,  4 < 28   ---->    true
print x[0]         ---->    4
*ip *= 2           ---->    *ip = 8
```

Iteration III:

```
*ip = 8,  8 < 28   ---->    true
print x[0]         ---->    8
*ip *= 2           ---->    *ip = 16
```

Iteration IV:

```
*ip = 16,  16 < 28 ---->    true
print x[0]         ---->    16
*ip *= 2           ---->    *ip = 32
```

Iteration V:

```
*ip = 32,  32 < 28 ---->    false
loop exits
```

Hence, you are getting output - 2, 4, 8, 16.

Correct way to get the size of an array is - `sizeof (x) / sizeof (x[0])`. This will result in number of elements of array `x`.

This

```
ip = &(x[0]);
```

can also written as

```
ip = x;
```

because when you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few *exceptions* to this rule). Moreover,

From C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..

by this definition

```
&(x[0]) -> &(*(x + 0)) -> &(*(x)) -> x
```

You are initialising the array `x` with an empty initialiser:

```
int x[7] = {}
```

Empty initialiser is non-conforming in C, though some C compilers accept it. Instead, you should do:

```
int x[7] = {0}
```

Your desired output is 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 i.e. the first element of array should be `2` and every successive element in the array should be multiple of `2` of its previous element. Since, you want to calculate the value of every element of array using pointer pointing to that array element, one things you should know -

- A pointer can point to one past the last element of array but dereferencing it will invoke undefined behaviour.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int x[7] = {0}, *ip;

    ip = x;
    *ip = 2;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (x) / sizeof (x[0]); ++i) {
        printf ("value of x: %d\n", x[i]);

        // make pointer point to next element in array 
        ++ip;

        // make sure that the element that ip pointer pointing to is valid to deference
        if (ip < x + (sizeof (x)/sizeof (x[0]))) {
            // calculate the element value using the previous element value 
            *ip = *(ip - 1) * 2;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to avoid the pointer comparison, you may do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int x[7] = {0}, *ip;

    ip = x;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (x) / sizeof (x[0]); ++i, ++ip) {
        *ip = (i ? *(ip - 1) : 1) * 2;
        printf("value of x: %d\n", x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int x[7] = {}, *ip;
ip = &(x[0]);
```

In C, arrays are just pointers that you've told the proprocessor and compiler about so it can do the memory allocation on the stack for you. There's nothing special about the pointer itself with an array. In the above, `ip` and `x` are both int*, so you can just say `ip = x;`

```
*ip = 2;
```

x[0] now is 2

```
for(int i = 0; *ip < sizeof x; *ip *= 2){
```

Your middle condition `*ip < sizeof x;` in English is *"until the int pointed to by ip is less than the number of bytes used by x (7 * sizeof(int); probably 7 * 4 or 28)"* It's valid in that it will compile and execute, but I don't think it's what you want looking at the rest of your code. You never increment ip, so it's always changing x[0].

Assuming you just don't want ip to go past the end of x[], You could write this as `i < sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` which is *"counter i is less than the total bytes used by x[] divided by the size in bytes of one element used by x (the number of elements in x[])"* or if you want to use `ip` and not `i` for some reason `ip <= &x[6]` which is *"ip is less than or equal to the address of the last element of x[] (because we know x is a fixed length of 7; [0...6]"*

```
*ip *= 2
```

Your for incrementor is *"the integer pointed to by ip is multiplied by 2"*. Normally you would increment your counter `i` here, but it's acceptable in C to do something else like you have here. However, since you never change ip, this is going to multiply the same x[0] by 2 over and over until x[0]'s value is more than sizeof(x). You probably want to increment ip or i here, so it steps through X[]. Normally the manipulation of your array would happen inside the for block and not in the for control statements.

```
printf("value of x: %d\n", x[i]);
```

This will always print the value of x[0], since i never changes.

Everything you've written is valid C code. Some of the things you're doing are unusual, but there are edge cases where you would want that in C, for example incrementing something other than your counter in the for loop control. However, you've got a extra code that isn't doing anything useful. I see what you want as output from your question details, but from your code I'm unsure how you want to accomplish that, so this is just a guess:

```
int x[7];
x[0] = 2;
printf("x[0] starts with: %d\n",x[0]);

for(int i = 1; i<sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); i++) { //i start at 1 because we already set x[0]
  x[i] = x[i-1]*2; //the current x[] = double the previous x[] 
  printf("value of x[%d]: %d\n",i,x[i]);
}
```

This version fills x with [2,4,8,16,32,64,128]. The `int *ip` isn't needed- there are times you'll want to control a loop with pointer math, but it's not needed here.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers - they are objects made up of a contiguous number of elements of a common type.  The preprocessor knows nothing about arrays either, it only operates based on tokens with no semantic analysis other than constant arithmetic.

Comment: There are no objects in C. There are only memory pointers and primitives/registers. Even an allocated struct is just a pointer with named offsets the compiler uses to do offset math to get the memory address the programmer wants. With `int x[7]` and `int *ip` there is literally no pointer difference between x and ip. The compiler will automatically allocate memory on the stack for x. That's the only difference. There no difference with regard to the pointers- any pointer operation on one can be done on the other.

Comment: See section 3.15 of the C11 standard where "object" is defined. A struct isn't a pointer either, you're mistaken about the basics of the C memory model.  `x` and `ip` are different as evinced by `sizeof x` and `sizeof ip` ; the result of `sizeof` is how many "stack" bytes the compiler will allocate.

Comment: An *allocated* struct is just a pointer, x and ip are just pointers. Sizeof relates to stack use of x[], that doesn't change x being a pointer. Any dimensional arrays are just pointers with info for the preprocessor and compiler to do math for you and stack allocation. This will probably blow your mind but with most C compilers pointers and ints are synonymous. You can access arrays, pointers, allocated structs all with ints or any type of pointer (except on compilers like Microsoft's where int isn't register-sized.) If you don't believe me compile a sample C program and dump out the assembly.

Comment: Try reading the language standard. It's probably new to you if you only learned by trial and error but you have some deep misunderstanding of the basic concepts .

Comment: I've been working professional with C for about 25 years, much of that mixing C and assembly. There will come a point where you realize a pointer is a pointer is usually an int, especially if you work on embedded systems.